# Run batch file without getting prints on variables declarations [octave]

Tags: batch-file, octave, numerical-analysis

I'm working with a script file in octave. The problem is that it gets really messy when I declare big matrices because it prints them onto the command prompt.

Is there an easy way to prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by placing semicolons after the variable declarations.